# Android6 registration toke on cordova push plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using ionic and the Cordova push plugin for notification. When I upgrade my device to android 6, I don't get registration token from the device. But still my codes work with no problem on devices with lower android versions. 
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem with CSP rules. After fixing that, my problem was solved.